# Passing optional arguments to a function (where they are also optional)

Tags: function, coldfusion, optional-arguments

## Background

I am experiencing a problem when I attempt to pass optional arguments to another function. The function being called also has optional arguments so I'm trying to get that optionality to propagate all the way through.

The problem I'm experiencing is that since cold fusion doesn't have a concept of null ([or at least not really](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1654-learning-coldfusion-9-isnull-and-working-with-null-values.htm)) when an optional argument is omitted it literally doesn't exist.

```
component accessors=true output=false persistent=false {
    public void function foo(String otherOptional, String optional1,String optional2 ){

        //Other code
        //Other code
        //Other code
        bar(optional1=optional1,optional2=optional2);

    }

    public void function bar(String optional1, String optional2 ){
         //Other code
    }
}
```

For example in the above code if `foo` is called without any arguments I receive an error

```
Variable OPTIONAL1 is undefined.

The error occurred in D:/web/experimental/OptionalTest.cfc: line 11
9 : 
10 :        //Other code
11 :        bar(optional1=optional1,optional2=optional2);
12 : 
13 :    }
```

## Question

Is there a way to pass optional arguments to another function where they are also optional without causing errors?

Solutions I've considered are:

- Passing `argumentcollection=arguments`. But that seems deeply unpleasant since it makes it very hard to read which arguments are really needed by bar (I've tried to debug code like this, it isn't fun). Also it doesn't work if different argument names are used by `foo` and `bar`
- A series of if StructKeyExists statement to only pass an optional argument if it exists. This would work but could get very complicated very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that involves StructKeyExists but probably in a way that's different from what you've already considered:

```
bar(
  optional1 = StructKeyExists(arguments, 'optional1') ? arguments.optional1 : JavaCast('null', 0),
  optional2 = StructKeyExists(arguments, 'optional2') ? arguments.optional2 : JavaCast('null', 0)
);
```

Comment: Interesting, this is indeed far better than the mess I'd imagined using StructKeyExists would cause. I had imagined using structkeyexists the other way round, with it outside bar (and so every variety of bar being used in foo)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to default them out

So in your example, you can tell CF that `optional1` equals `""`:

```
component accessors=true output=false persistent=false {
  public void function foo(String otherOptional="", String optional1="",String optional2="" ){

    //Other code
    //Other code
    //Other code
    bar(optional1=optional1,optional2=optional2);

  }

  public void function bar(String optional1, String optional2 ){
     //Other code
     if(len(optional1)){
       //do this
     }

     //etc
  }
}
```

Comment: Assuming I have control of all the functions this does seem ideal (which may end up being the case as what I'm looking at is such a mess it needs a heavy refactor). Setting defaults for optional arguments feels like a good idea in general. I won't accept yet in case an answer that doesn't require modifying bar presents itself

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but it is crazy that the most correct answer isn't here. Yes you can use structKeyExists on the arugments scope, but you can also just use isDefined('argumentname'), which has been an option since CF3.

From the docs:
Evaluates a string value to determine whether the variable named in it exists. This function is an alternative to the ParameterExists function, which is deprecated.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/isdefined.html